# Objective-C dataWithContentsOfURL returns nill

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this code here:

```
NSString *stringURL = @"\\\\SERVER\\FOLDER\\FOLDER\\FTP\\ANC\\ANC.pdf";    
NSURL  *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:stringURL];
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

but urlData returned nill

I have tried datawithcontentsoffile but I got a warning when using the url variable with it.

When I goto this url file://SERVER/FOLDER/FOLDER/FTP/ANC.pdf in Windows, it opens the file, but on mac it does not not.

I have also tried the following:

```
NSString *stringURL = @"file://SERVER/FOLDER/FOLDER/FTP/ANC.pdf"; 
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
[[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringURL]
            completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                NSURLResponse *response,
                                NSError *error) {
                // handle response

            }] resume];

// NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];  
// NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

but get these errors:

```
NSErrorFallingURLStringKey
NSErrorFallingURLKey
NSLocalizedDescription
NSUnderlyingError
```

UPDATE I am able to get url not return nill with the following:

```
NSURL  *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"file:///server/FOLDER/FOLDER/FTP/ANC/ANC.pdf"];
```

however, this returns nill:

```
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

I added the error: to dataWithContentsofURL

and it returned this:

```
connectionError NSError *   domain: @"NSCocoaErrorDomain" - code: 260   0x166d8af0
```

I looked at the file in question via Get Info and it starts out like this `smb://server/folder/folder/ANC/ANC.pdf`

Comment: Is `url == nil` as well?

Comment: nope, url is not equal to nil

Comment: Is this a remote file? I guess so since you write "SERVER". `fileURLWithPath` will only return local filesystem URL's. Try `URLWithString` instead.

Comment: this is a remote file

Comment: I just tried using URLWithString instead of fileURLWithPath but the url variable returned nill

Comment: What kind of protocol does the server use to serve the file? HTTP/FTP or something? I imagine the correct solution for this would be to download the file with `NSURLSession`, for example.

Comment: The code you posted isn't too helpful because you haven't posted a real URL. If it is really a remote URL, it needs to be a proper URL such as `http://somedomain.com/path/to/file/ANC.pdf`. URLs require a real URL scheme (http, ftp, etc.), a real domain name or IP address. And URLs use forward slashes, not backslashes.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad The OP stated in a comment that it is a remote URL. Therefore using ,`fileURLWithPath` is wrong. And using a remote URL requires a proper scheme and everything else.

Comment: Ah,yes, did not read that. Sorry.

Comment: Why not make a sample project for us to debug and help instead of letting us estimate where the problem might be?

Comment: can u share your sample of code i will check @ xcode 7.1.

Comment: The file in question doesn't have the ftp part in it , could you just have an incorrect path in your code?

Comment: If you're trying to go through ftp, this might help: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Listings/Read_Me_About_SimpleFTPSample_txt.html

Comment: The string you have (`\\SERVER\FOLDER\FOLDER\FTP\ANC\ANC.pdf`) is not a valid path on OS X. Nor is it a URL string. It is something that's basically only meaningful on Windows. You need to obtain a valid OS X path or URL before you go any further.

Answer (score 7):

#### NSData and URLs: There be dragons

`+[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]` can return `nil` for any number of reasons. If *anything* goes wrong when attempting to use that URL this method will return `nil`. For example the file may not exist, the network connection may time out, or the URL may even be malformed. `nil` is returned and the application has no idea why.

`+ [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:]` on the other hand, *will* tell the caller what went wrong. When `nil` is returned the `error` argument will be populated with an object that describes the problem that occured. Using this method would directly answer the question of "why".

Both of these are synchronous methods and their use for working with files, network resources, and especially files served from a network resource is discouraged. These methods will block the caller and are not really intended for these kinds of uses. It's better to use an input stream or `NSURLSession` instead.

#### SMB Not Supported

From your question though it seems you are trying to access a file that exists on an SMB share. Unforunately iOS does not support SMB - even if you had a correctly formatted smb URL (i.e. smb://servername/sharename/filename.pdf) you would be unable to access it without using a third party SMB implementation.

Using FTP in place of SMB, however, should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to do some minor change, Actually your pdf file is on server so you have to change your code like this.

```
NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
```

I tried this and its working fine.

If your file is in application's main bundle than you can use `fileURLWithPath`.

Comment: That's not true; the url will use the `file://` scheme and using `fileURLWithPath:` will cope with spaces in the path, unlike `URLWithString:`.

Comment: I tried this and with the URL file:// and it didn;t work, urlData was nill

Comment: It's probably got more to do with backspaces, which is a Windows thing, than anything else...

Comment: if I use \\ I get nill for url

Answer (score 0):

If you have a valid windows file path with backslash separators, there is a `CoreFoundation` method to convert it to a `CFURL`/`NSURL` object

```
NSString *stringURL = @"\\\\SERVER\\FOLDER\\FOLDER\\FTP\\ANC\\ANC.pdf";
NSURL *url = (NSURL *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault, stringURL, kCFURLWindowsPathStyle, false));
```

If the string starts with `file://` it's a Mac URL string with the `file` scheme and you can use

```
NSString *fileURLString = @"file:///Applications";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fileURLString];
```

**Consider that a valid file scheme string must have a third slash for the root folder after the two slashes for the scheme.**

The method `fileURLWithPath` can only be used if the string starts with a single slash, it adds the `file://` scheme implicitly.

```
NSString *pathString = "/Applications";
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: pathString];
```

Comment: I tried solution number 2 & 3 the url is not nill, but this returns nill `NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];`

Comment: I tried solution number 1 and got these errors `Cast of C pointer type 'CFURLRef' (aka 'const struct __CFURL *') to Objective-C pointer type 'NSURL *' requires a bridged cast` and `/Users/jsuske/Documents/SSiPad(Device Only)ios7 copy/SchedulingiPadApplication/ViewControllers/LHFileBrowser.m:148:82: Incompatible pointer types passing retainable parameter of type 'NSString *__strong'to a CF function expecting 'CFStringRef' (aka 'const struct __CFString *') type`

Comment: actually the compiler suggests a solution for the bridge cast, I edited the post

Answer (score 0):

Make sure URL contains `http://` OR `https://`.
For example: `http://SERVER/FOLDER/FILE.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

Two things to keep in mind while accessing a file in iOS application:

- If you are accessing a file from iOS application sandbox(document or cache directory) then use this:

  ```
  NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:strUrl];
  ```
- If you are accessing a file from any server in iOS application then use this:

  ```
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strUrl];
  ```

NOTE: You cannot access a file from your mac in iOS application when running from simulator.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

please check your code with this code

```
 -(void)downloadPdfBtnPressed:(id)sender
    {
        NSString *dowloadURL = [DownloadUrlArray objectAtIndex:[sender tag ]];
        NSString *filename =[dowloadURL lastPathComponent];

        NSString *stringPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Download"];


        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:stringPath])
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:stringPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];

        NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:dowloadURL]];
        if(pdfData)
        {
            stringPath = [stringPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
            [pdfData writeToFile:stringPath atomically:YES];



            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[singletonObj getTranslationForKey:@"AlereTitleContactus"]
                                                            message:@"PDF file is downloaded"
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:[singletonObj getTranslationForKey:@"alertOK"]
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }
```